# set oracle user Display so i can install

Tags: oracle, unix, xlib

running oracle enterprise linux

the Oracle installer keeps telling me that my DISPLAY variable isn't set. however echo display clearly prints ":0.0"

logged in as root I am able to run xclock to launch the app, but when I "su oracle" and then run xclock it refuses

```
[oracle@devsebl ~] xclock
Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified

Error: Can't open display: :0.0
```

how can i give the oracle user permissions to use the display??

Comment: i tried setting the DISPLAY variable to my ip address 192.168.XX:0.0 as defined by /etc/hosts but then it no longer works on root or oracle

Comment: fixed it...i had to add localhost to xhost first

xhost +localhost

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cannot-open-display-as-root-352200/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed it...i had to add localhost to xhost first

```
xhost +localhost
```

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cannot-open-display-as-root-352200/